# Hacer hover a un elemento y afectar a otro solo con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
$('.text-center h1').hover(function(){
  $('.destacada img').css({
    "width": "100px", //O lo que desees
    "height": "100px" //O lo que desees
  });
});
```

Vi en otra publicacion que se puede hacer esto con jquery pero quisiera hacerlo solo con Javascript si se puede alguien que me ayude

Answer (score 0):

```css
#t{
background-color:red;
width:32px;
height:32px;

}
```

```html
<div id='t' onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" ></div>



<script>
function bigImg(x) {
  x.style.height = "64px";
  x.style.width = "64px";
}

function normalImg(x) {
  x.style.height = "32px";
  x.style.width = "32px";
}
</script>
```